# Sentiment Analysis - should I normalise positive and negative word lists when they differ in length?

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm implementing a simple sentiment analysis algorithm where the authors of the paper have a word list for positive and negative words and simply count the number of occurrences of each in the analysed document and give it a sentiment score the document with:

sentiment = (#positive_matches - #negative_matches) / (document_word_count)

This is normalising the sentiment score by document length BUT the corpus of negative words is 6 times larger than the positive word corpus (around 300 positive words and 1800 negative words) so by the measure above, the sentiment score will likely be negatively biased since there are more negative words to match than positive words.

How can I correct for the imbalance in the length of the positive vs. negative corpuses?

Should I adjust the sentiment score to normalize each positive/negative count by the respective corpus lengths such that:

sentiment* = ((#positive_matches/#words_in_positive_corpus) - (#negative_matches/#words_in_negative_corpus)) / (document_word_count)

Any thoughts / sanity check / advice much appreciated :)

Comment: do you have any influence on the given positive/negative word lexicon?

Comment: Yes - I'm using the Loughran McDonald dictionary but it's entirely up to me

Comment: finding a good lexicon is always very valuable .. maybe you can cross check several lexicons and weigh the words based on the nr. of occurrences (see my answer)

Comment: I think my lexicon is good but I'm getting results that are more negative than I'd expect since I'd expect the 'true' sentiment of the documents to be symmetrically positive/negative yet I'm getting far more documents classified as negative than positive and I'm not sure how to fix this to reflect the underlying symmetrical distribution of sentiment. seems like more words to match negative sentiment is biasing my results?

Answer (score 1):

the formula you presented there is basically a bad idea, because if you have a sentence like:

"Today there is good and bad news about the company"

you would expect to have a neutral sentiment for this sentence.
When you use your formula the sentence gets a positive sentiment just because one lexicon is bigger/smaller then the other.

An idea would be to weigh the words in the lexicon (if you can modify it) so that you have e.g. 100 very strong sentiment words with a big weight and then the weight decreases if the word is not that important for sentiment calculation.
Now the difference in the lexica sizes doesn't matter that much anymore.

Comment: One immediate problem is how I take a list of 1800 words and weigh them based on 'importance'. I think it may be a natural feature of the English language that there are more ways of saying something negatively than positively. Or, as I'm inclined to believe, it may just be that 2-gram adverb-adjustments e.g. 'very profitable' are a more natural way of expressing positive sentiment. Perhaps the number of words in each list doesn't matter but I'd expect the sentiment of document set (around 2000 documents) to be approx. neutral overall but currently getting ~70% docs with negative sentiment.

Comment: Sentiment analysis is a very hard problem. Just by taking one lexicon and applying one simple formula you will hardly get any good results ... if you really want to dig into it and get good results you will have to dig deeper.. I suggest you take  a standard library OR start by reading some papers.. just doing a five minute implementation will not get you very far!!! it may be disappointing but it is just not that easy to automatically filter meaning... sorry

Comment: I'm fully aware that it is a hard problem. I'm not expecting to get far 'just doing a five minute implementation' - the reason I'm asking the question is because asymmetrical word lists are a theoretical consideration and I was hoping to get some input on that. Telling me to 'start by reading some papers' is disappointing because it's a sign of intellectual laziness on your part. I have read papers on the subject but this is a nuanced point which isn't going to come up in a google scholar search. If you cannot constructively respond to my question then rather don't respond at all.

Comment: I was about to post something similar. Dividing negative sentiment count by the size of your negative word list is dangerous. It may be that there are just more synonyms for negative concepts. I'd increase your positive list with some synonyms (e.g. run it through WordNet), then throw away the least common words from your negative list, until they are the same size. (E.g. define "least common" as lowest occurrence count in a large corpus.)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you can get good results with any lexicon based model when the corpus itself is biased. You can apply some normalization to minimize the bias, but still it won't give you good results.

Your simple Lexicon based models doesn't take into account phrases(n-grams), context , negation etc. Classifier based models like Naive Bays, Max Entropy or Support Vector Machine might give you better results.

You can also try a hybrid approach with both Lexicon and probabilistic model like Naive Bayes and compare the results but any approach will require either a good lexicon or trained data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the positive and negative lexicons then I would suggest use [this](https://github.com/uwescience/datasci_course_materials/blob/master/assignment1/AFINN-111.txt) list. I have used it in past and found it quite extensive as well as balanced. Also, it gives polarity intensity for each lexicon too. You can choose to use it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

As others already said, dictionary-based approach isn't promising for sentiment analysis. Especially if your dictionary is not expressly created for this task and not even domain-specific.

If you want to use such a method for some reason, try to search for other sentiment-aware dictionaries or methods for their obtainin, start from [here](http://agent.csie.ntu.edu.tw/system/papers/236/original/IS-28-02-Tsai-new.pdf) for example.

If you want to fix your dictionary, try to expand it (both positives and negatives) by synonyms from WordNet or other services, see suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4202441/4588780).

Nevertheless, what you are actually more interesting in is the unbiased distribution of the events like "message contains positive word" and "message contains negative word", but not the equal counts of positive and negative words. I mean, these 300 positive words can occur in texts (from your domain, which is important) not less often than these 1800 negative ones. 
Moreover, you don't know true distribution of positive and negative words (you assume that they are equally often, but why?) and thus you don't know if it is biased or not.